# Is it necessary to use AtomicInteger in a ThreadFactory?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, threadpool, atomicinteger

I think it's necessary to use `AtomicInteger` in the ThreadFactory but when I am trying to prove it to myself, I failed hard.

```
    new ThreadFactory() {

        private int threadId = 0;   <---- AtomicInteger preferred

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.setName("my-thread-" + (threadId++));   <--- dangerous code
            return t;
        }
    }
```

If several requests come, the thread factory will generate threads to handle them and during the generation, there **could** be a gap during which a **race condition** might sneak in.

I tried with the following code to demonstrate my theory, but it's not happening at all with **2_000** core threads.

```
@Slf4j
public class ThreadFactoryTest {

    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread> threadIdThreadMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private ThreadPoolExecutor myExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2000, 2000, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100000), new ThreadFactory() {

        private int threadId = 0;

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.setName("my-thread-" + (threadId++));
            if (threadIdThreadMap.contains(t.getName())) {
                log.error("already existed");
                System.err.println(myExecutor);
                myExecutor.shutdownNow();
            } else threadIdThreadMap.put(t.getName(), t);
            return t;
        }
    }, new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());

    @Test
    public void testThreadFactory() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            new Thread(() -> runOneHundredJobs()).start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
        myExecutor.shutdown();
        myExecutor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void runOneHundredJobs() {
        log.info("{} starting to submit tasks", Thread.currentThread().getName());
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
            myExecutor.execute(() -> {
                while (100 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        if (Math.random() > 0.99) break;
                        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println(myExecutor);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            } );
        }
    }
}
```

Looks like a stupid question since I always know that "*it's hard to create the gap for a multi-thread race condition*".

Any help/clue will be appreciated ;)

#### UPDATE

Really thanks for the help along the way, @StephenC and @Slaw. I am sorry that I misunderstood some points there ;(

So `newThread` should be implemented in a **thread-safe** way and then in my case, the `AtomicInteger` is required. And I wanna have a quote from StephenC:

> Failure to demonstrate a race condition doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Starting a thread is a long process, so very difficult to get exact alignment.  How about creating your threads and having them all start by waiting on the same lock, or all waiting until 3pm, etc.  That way, they'll all start running from the same fixed point, so more likely to get that race condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it necessary to use AtomicInteger in a ThreadFactory?

It will depend on how the factory object is used.

- If you supply a different factory object to each instance of `ThreadPoolExecutor` then the (actual) concurrency requirements for the factory will depend on how the executor uses it.  In the absence of statements in the javadocs, you would need to examine the source code. I haven't checked, but I suspect that expansion of the thread pool (including the call to `newThread`) happen inside a mutex.  If my suspicion is correct, then this use-case doesn't require the factory object to be thread-safe.

  **UPDATE** - I have now checked, and my suspicion was *incorrect* (for Java 8 & 12).  The `newThread` call is made when creating a new `Worker` object, and that is not done while holding a mutex.  Therefore, your `newThread` method needs to be thread-safe in this context too.
- If a factory object is shared with other things (e.g. another executor) then you are correct: your `newThread` method needs to be thread-safe.

---

I haven't looked at your code to try to show race conditions, but to my mind, that's not the best way to go about this.  Code inspection and reasoning is a better way.  Failure to demonstrate a race condition doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen, I love this word of yours **Failure to demonstrate a race condition doesn't mean it doesn't exist.**.

Comment: But I am not getting your idea in this: >>> but I suspect that expansion of the thread pool (including the call to newThread) happen inside a mutex. If my suspicion is correct, then this use-case doesn't require the factory object to be thread-safe.<<< since it's not wrapped inside a mutex, shouldn't it require the thread factory **thread-safe**?

Comment: An executor is required to be thread-safe.  (If it wasn't, it would be not-fit-for-purpose.)  Therefore, we assume internal operations like expanding the thread pool must be thread-safe.  The obvious way to do this is to use a mutex.  (Using a primitive lock, or some other locking mechanism with appropriate *happens-before* semantics.) The thread factory `newThread` would be called while within that mutex.  Thus, the call to `newThread` is externally synchronized, and therefore doesn't need to be thread-safe.  (Note that this reasoning only applies if the factory is not shared.)

Comment: Looking at the Java 12 implementation, it doesn't look like `ThreadPoolExecutor` synchronizes on a mutex when creating a `Worker` (whose constructor invokes `ThreadFactory#newThread`). It does for other things, but not that. Also, my own tests (similar to OP's) fail: expected count is 2000 but actual count (when not atomic/synchronized) ends up being 1998 or 1999. Whereas the expected and actual counts _are_ equal when using `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the idea, I tried with the test enclosed in the question, there will be **2_000** in my case (java8) not using `AtomictInteger`.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for the help, but I found no `mutex` you mentioned in the answer, I enclosed my clue in my answer. Would you please help to provide your source link? Thank you for any help ;)

Comment: @Slaw, thanks. But I saw it and read it. He also mentioned: >>> The newThread call is made when creating a new Worker object, and that is not done while holding a mutex. Therefore, the newThread method should be **thread-safe**.<<< and that's why I am asking for another help here ;P

Comment: @Hearen If I understand your confusion correctly, Stephen means _your `ThreadFactory` implementation_ must be thread-safe, not that `ThreadPoolExecutor` calls `newThread` in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Yes.  I said the method, not the call to the method.   And if you read / understand what I was saying earlier in the answer, I was incorrectly hypothesizing that the method did not need to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I am making the test simpler to make the expected result emerge from under the water.

With the test below, the expected thread size is `1000` sharp while using `int` will give a `less` size oftentimes (994, 996, 999 in my macOS), *not all the times*.

```
public class ThreadFactoryTest {
    private ConcurrentHashMap<String, Thread> threadIdThreadMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    private ThreadPoolExecutor myExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2000, 2000, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100000), new ThreadFactory() {

        private int threadId = 0;
        private AtomicInteger atomicThreadId = new AtomicInteger(0);

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.setName("my-thread-" + (threadId++));
            // uncomment this line, the thread size will be less than 1000
            t.setName("my-thread-" + (atomicThreadId.getAndIncrement()));
            threadIdThreadMap.put(t.getName(), t);
            return t;
        }
    }, new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());



    @Test
    public void testThreadFactory() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
            new Thread(() -> runOneHundredJobs()).start();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000000);
        myExecutor.shutdown();
        myExecutor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void runOneHundredJobs() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            myExecutor.execute(() -> {
                while (100 < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        log.warn("count: {}", threadIdThreadMap.size());
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```